# What will be the accurate Regular Expression for my String?

Tags: java, regex

An example string:

> **AB-XYZ-123**

Where:

**`AB`** : Any two capital alphabets only, no symbol, no numbers, no Small letter alphabets.

**`-`**  : A `-` symbol only, nothing else.

**`XYZ`**: Any three capital characters capital letter alphabets combination.

**`-`**  : A `-` symbol only, nothing else.

**`123`**: Any three numbers (*[0-9]*) combination.

and yeah I am very weak in creating regex.

Comment: Might want to read through some of http://regular-expressions.info. It explains a ton about regexes.

Comment: +1 for info. . i'll go thorough it later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{3}$
```

Comment: Better would be: `^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{3}$`

Comment: Sorry...java compiler says: `Illegal Escape Character` at \. . .Can I use \\ instead?

Comment: @Asif: Yes, use double backslash to escape a backslash in Java.

Answer (score 2):

It is

```
^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{3}$
```